# How to exclude a transaction from result file

Tags: jmeter

During my jmeter test execution.I want to exclude a transaction to be saved into jtl file.Does anyone know how can we resolve this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to remove a transaction is to simply remove it from the jtl after the test. Obviously, this is cumbersome to do manually with large files.

If you're running on Linux, you can run something like this:

```
grep -v [your excluded sampler name] [your jtl name] > [new jtl name]
```

This is particularly useful if you execute your scripts from a CI tool- it's simply another step in the job. For example, many of my scripts use BeanShell Samplers. I don't want to include them, so I preface them all with "(BS)". In my Jenkins job, I run the command

`grep -v "\(BS\)" /Results/my_job.jtl > /Results/NoBS_my_job.jtl`

When I run my report generator, I simply call in on the `NoBS_my_job.jtl` version.